# Using Pico VR headset Having issues with Key inputs not reading

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-input, virtual-reality

So I'm having a pico and a quest headset and I've set up some key mappings using unitys input system and there is something that gets called as I press the Trigger button on the controller which works perfectly in the quest but for some reason the generic XR controller keys inside the Input asset do no work with Pico's headset nothing happens as I click for some reason, has anyone used this headset?? Please help!

Was trying to setup input actions in unity with the Pico headset which works with Oculus quest but not pico